# Who can recommend a good quality assembly language basic textbooks?

Tags: assembly

Who can recommend a good quality assembly language basic textbooks?

Comment: hmm assembly & basic? hahahaha!!

Comment: I'm currently in writing an entry level x86-64 assembly tutorial for programmers which might or might not be what you are looking for: https://plus.google.com/111794994501300143213/posts/9gxSUZMJUF2

Answer (score 2):

[The Art of Assembly Language Programming](http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/artofasm.html)

[Assembly Language Step-by-step: Programming with DOS and Linux](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471375233)

[Mastering Turbo Assembler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672484358)

Had already been answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199679/good-beginners-books-for-assembly-languages

Comment: +1 the art of assembly language is wonderful, totally recommended!

Comment: Mastering Turbo Assembler by Tom Swan or the book by Randall Hyde

Answer (score 2):

The best I ever found, assuming you actually did the exercises, was Knuth "The Art of Computer Programming", vol. 1, "Fundamental Algorithms".

Comment: Doesn't Knuth use some kind of theoritical machine language?Similar to pseudocode?How could the OP learn assembly from TAOP?

Comment: Yeah, that book uses an obscure assembly language

Comment: Today, the "popular" assembly language is 80x86.  30-40 years ago, it was IBM 360.  Having been in this racket for something over 30 years, having dealt with something like twenty different (some VERY different) machines (counting all variants of the 80x86 as one (1) machine), when someone asks me for an assembly language text, I tend to assume he wants to learn how to approach assembly language programming on ANY processor.  That's what Knuth teaches.